# How to use the spread operator in a typescript tuple?

Tags: typescript, types, tuples, spread-syntax

I want to specify how the rest of the array should look without knowing how many values the array will have. How can I achieve something like this? (playground version [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=type%20numStrArr%20%3D%20%5Bnumber%2C%20...string%5D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20arr%3A%20numStrArr%20%3D%20%5B1%2C%20'hi'%2C%20'other%20string'%5D%3B)):

```
type numStrArr = [number, ...string];

let arr: numStrArr = [1, 'hi', 'other string'];
```

The above code throws the error `Type expected.` at the spread operator, however.

I'm aware that there was a [proposal](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5296) for this, but how can I achieve similar behavior now?

Comment: You should probably use an object instead of an array.

Comment: I know that would work, I'm just interested how this would work aswell

Comment: I think this is impossible. You could use `[number, string]` or `{0: number, [i: number]: string | number}`, but both of them would type additional params as `number | string`, not `string`. Closest you could get is probably something like `[number, string, string, string, string, string, string]`.

Comment: Played with this a bit, the best I could come up with is an interface extending Array. Playground link is too long. I can't really see any use case for this that isn't better handled by using objects...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I know this question is 3 years old, but the feature is supported now. All you need to do is change the type to a type that can be spread. Read more about it [here](https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/future-javascript/spread-operator):

```
// no more error...
type numStrArr = [number, ...string[]];
```